# Perform test in R to check if all tests are present for every 35-37 rows of dataset

Tags: r, loops

I have a dataset which contains around 35-37 tests for each participant. Something like this:

| Participant_ID | Test_ID |
| --- | --- |
| 71822 | 2125 |
| 71822 | 2167 |
| 71822 | 2145 |
| 71822 | 2189 |
| 71822 | 2143 |

The data contains 35-37 rows of for each participant and their respective test results.

**I want to automatize this task where I can check if the test for any participant is less than 35 then it should say False otherwise True.**

I tried to do following to check if at least following tests are present for each particiapant

```
test_ID <-   c("2125", "2167", "2145", "2189", "2143")

  dat %>% 
  group_by(Paticipant_ID) %>% 
  test_ID %in% as.matrix(dat$Test_ID)
```

Comment: `data %>% group_by(Participant_ID) %>% count()` will give you a list of the count for each one, which will do the job assuming no participant may have duplicate tests.

Comment: Thanks! this was easy and a better solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To test how many rows there are per participant:

```
library(tidyverse)
data %>% group_by(Participant_ID) %>% count()
```

to show which combinations are missing:

```
# get a list of every combination of participant and test
allOptions <- expand.grid(unique(data$Participant_ID), unique(data$Test_ID))
names(allOptions) <- names(data)
# look for missing ones
anti_join(allOptions, data)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't understand function of anti_join here, it just gives me all combination of tests and IDs that I have in the data but I don't see the missing values.

Comment: The line that creates allOptions should give you a data frame containing all possible unique combinations of Participant ID and Test ID.  The `anti_join()` call looks for any row of the "allOptions" table that is not also seen in the true data - i.e. it should list only missing tests.